# Using WSDL.exe with local WSDL file that has external .xsd files

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl.exe

I'm trying to generate a Web Service stub from some wsdl/xsd files that a customer has sent us. I've done this with no problems using wsdl.exe before while everything was in the wsdl file, but when I run the file on the wsdl file I get an error message stating that is can't import one of the operations because one of the elements that is in an external xsd is missing.

I've tried putting a schemeLocation parameter in the  element and it's still not working. Is there a way to state what the xsds are when calling wsdl.exe?

I can't post the wsdl files because they covered by an NDA.

Comment: Are there missing elements in the external xsd? Re-check namespaces is my first thought as that usually can be a problem.

Comment: the namespace is the same as the one in the file, I just think it's not loading the xsd with the definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out you can have multiple file names as the parameters to WSDL.exe if you include the xsd files after the wsdl file it works fine...

Comment: It's great to know we can, but this answer would have been awesome if you could have shared 'how' :)

Comment: Just separate the file names with spaces.